# Set a global variable before //= require in .js file (rails)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I'm using Rails 4.

I have the following .js file (an example only):

```
//= require foo.js
```

Now I would like to influence the behaviour of foo.js by setting a global variable.  So I have the following:

```
var fooType = 'abc';
//= require foo.js
```

And foo.js has the following:

```
$(function() {
    if(window.Handlebars && $('#some-id').length) {
        if (typeof fooType == 'undefined') {
            fooType = 'xyz';
        }
        Somelib.init(fooType);
    }
});
```

However, this does NOT work.  In fact, foo.js doesn't seem to be loaded at all.

The following works:

```
//= require foo.js
var fooType = 'abc';
```

Can someone please explain this?

Also, is using a global variable a good practice in this case?  If not, how else can I accomplish this?

Comment: using a global variable is not a good practice at all. you can use window.varname to influence any behavior u like.

Comment: I think all the global variables are set before the document ready event firing, which is when the variable is needed.  Also, I think //= require just loads the file which sets up an event handler, which is not fired until the document is ready.

Answer (score 0):

require statements only work if they're the first lines of a file, you could solve this by creating a js file with all your contstants in:

```
//= require constants.js
//= require foo.js
```

then in constants.js add your global var

```
var fooType = 'abc';
```

probably not a good idea to do this - why not simply put it at the top of your foo.js file?

Comment: Thank you.  `fooType` is a parameter to influence the behaviour of foo.js.  foo.js is used by different web applications, which need to customize the behaviour of foo.js.  That's why I need to pass a parameter from outside foo.js.